# YupSchema. how validate only first element of array in YupSchema

Tags: javascript, arrays, validation, yup

I have this schema:

```
const YupSchema = (t: TFunction) =>
Yup.object().shape({
    name: Yup.string()
        .required('*')
        .max(49, 'maxСharacters' + ' 50'),
    areas: Yup.array().required('*'),        
    activities: Yup.array().of(
        Yup.object().shape({
            id: Yup.string().required('*'),
            pictureGood: Yup.string().required(
                'Required'
            ),
            pictureBad: Yup.string().required(
                'Required'
            ),
            translations: Yup.array() /* <=== hear I need get only first element in array*/
                .of(
                    Yup.object().shape({
                        name: Yup.string().required('*'),
                        desc: Yup.string()
                            .required('*')
                            .max(999, 'maxСharacters' + ' 1000'),
                       
                        locale: Yup.string()
                            .required('*')
                            .max(999, 'maxСharacters' + ' 1000')
                    })
                )
                .required('Translations Required')
        })
    )
})
```

For this data object:

```
[{"id":"","activitiId":"1","pictureGood":[],"pictures":[],"translations":[{"generalDesc":"test","descGood":"test","descBad":"test","locale":"IT"},"generalDesc":"test","descGood":"test","descBad":"test","locale":"EN"}]}]
```

But I need to validate only the first element in the array, not all. something like this:
.

...

```
translations: Yup.array()[0]
            .of(
                Yup.object().shape({
                    name: Yup.string().required('*'),
```

...

Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to do the same, and I could see the "index" property coming in once I extended my "from" object as per:
https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/49512
...but I couldn't get at the index.

So using that technique (which I'll copy below for full answer here) I managed to ALSO extend the "options" object coming from the TextContext, then extend the "ValidateOptions" object (which I could see by stepping through in the browser where I could see index values!) - and therefore I could check which index I was at for my test in the array (as it loops through all items in the array).

I run this yup.test() over the array, and simply chuck out anything that wasn't index=0 for example (index === 0 in react/javascript of course!).

So my solution is:

```
interface ValidateOptionsExtended {
    options: {
        index: number;
    };
}

Yup.array().of(
    Yup.object().shape({
         outletId: yup
            .string()
            .trim()
            .nullable()
            .test('firstOutletAlwaysMandatory', 'Organisation name is required', function (item) {
                        const { from } = this as yup.TestContext & TestContextExtended;
                        const { options } = this as yup.TestContext & ValidateOptionsExtended;
                        // if not index 0 then exit we are not checking others here
                        if (options.index > 0) {
                           return true; 
                        }

                        ...check required value etc for index 0 here...
```

Answer (score 0):

In this code, you have provision to check only first element of array

```
const YupSchema = (t: TFunction) =>
  Yup.object().shape({
    name: Yup.string()
      .required('*')
      .max(49, 'maxСharacters' + ' 50'),
    areas: Yup.array().required('*'),
    activities: Yup.array().of(
      Yup.object().shape({
        id: Yup.string().required('*'),
        pictureGood: Yup.string().required('Required'),
        pictureBad: Yup.string().required('Required'),
        translations: Yup.array(
          Yup.object({
            name: Yup.string().required('*'),
            desc: Yup.string().required('*').max(999, 'maxСharacters' + ' 1000'),
            locale: Yup.string().required('*').max(999, 'maxСharacters' + ' 1000')
          })
        ).test('check-first-element', VOYAGE_ERRORS.TRACTOR_RUNWAY, function () {
          const { parent } = this;
          const firstEle = parent[0];

          if (firstEle.name === '' || firstEle.desc === '' || firstEle.locale === '') return false;

          return true;
        })
      })
    )
  })
```